# Why Solr search is giving zero values in this case

Tags: magento, solr, jetty

I've got this problem that I can't solve. Partly because I can't explain it with the right terms. I'm new to this so sorry for this clumsy question.

Below you can see an overview of my goal.

I'm using Magento CE 1.7.0.2 & Solr 4.6.0.

Here you can see my goal..

```
http://127.0.0.1:8055/solr/collection1/select?q="mens+jeans"&indent=true&defType=dismax&pf=fulltext&qs=2
```

In this case its giving exact products But if i'm searching with **jeans mens** means its giving zero products.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8055/solr/collection1/select?q="jeans+mens"&indent=true&defType=dismax&pf=fulltext&qs=2
```

But i want to get same products for the both cases...

Any Ideas ?

Comment: The problem lies probarly with how the data is parsed before indexation. Can you share the relevant parts of you schema.xml?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on you have indexed your docs (like Denis wrote at the comment) or it also could depends on your default searching settings.

For example: If all your queries are executed as a phrase-search, so it could be the situation, that your text contains `mens ... jeans` but never `jeans ...mens`

You should use an tokenizer and try to use the same field-settings for index- and search-time.

Looking at you solr-webpage you, probably, can use this link: `http://127.0.0.1:8055/solr/#/collection1/analysis` There you can see, how solr handles the different kind of queries.

This "Analysis"-Feature helps to optimize the field-settings for index- and search-time.